# Testing polynomials irreducible over the integers

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory, conjectures

Let $f\in\operatorname{int}(\mathbb Z)$, the ring of integer-valued rational polynomials. Define $\operatorname{P}^+(f)$ as the number of primes $>0$ that $f$ assumes at distinct integral arguments.

**Theorem**: If $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ is reducible of degree $n>0$, then $\operatorname{P}^+(f)\leq n$. And for all $n>0$ there are reducible polynomials of degree n such that $\operatorname{P}^+(f)=n$.
[Acta Arith.,104.2 (2002) 117-127.]

A lot of irreducible polynomials $f$ has a fixed divisor $>1$ and for those $\operatorname{P}^+(f)\leq n$.

> **Conjecture**: $f\in\mathbb Z[X]$ of degree $n>0$ with coprime coefficients is irreducible, iff $\;\operatorname{P}^+(d^{-1}\cdot f)>
> n$ or $\;\operatorname{P}^+(d^{-1}\cdot (-f))>
> n$, where $d$ is the greatest fixed divisor of $f$.

Is this known and proved?

---

Tested with a program using the conjectured statement on $1,000,000$ Eisenstein polynomials $f$ with random coefficients between $-19$ and $19$ and random degree between $2$ and $5$, without counter-examples.

Comment: Does not Bunyakovsky conjecture expect that there are infinitely many primes of such form?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: only if $d=1$ due to Wikipedia. But I think there is a variant of the conjecture with that expectation. http://www.hri.res.in/~thanga/papers/mnl.pdf page 32.